# How to upload image to php server from angular2 using PrimeNg?

Tags: angular, file-upload, primeng

my app.component.ts code

```
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
//import the do function to be used with the http library.
import "rxjs/add/operator/do";
import {FileUploadModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
//import the map function to be used with the http library
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import {AccordionModule} from 'primeng/primeng';      
import {MenuItem} from 'primeng/primeng';            //api
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template:  '<p-fileUpload name="myfile[]" url="./upload.php"> </p-fileUpload>'  ,
})
export class AppComponent   {
 name = 'Angular';
}
```

---

my app.module.ts code

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core'; 
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'; 
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http' 
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component'; 
import { FormSubmitionComponent } from "./components/form.component"; 
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms" 
import {AccordionModule} from 'primeng/primeng';      
import {MenuItem,FileUploadModule} from 'primeng/primeng';            
@NgModule({<br>
  imports:      [ BrowserModule,FormsModule ,HttpModule,FileUploadModule], 
  declarations: [ AppComponent ,FormSubmitionComponent], 
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ] 
})
export class AppModule { }
```

---

code from 
 https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/fileupload
when i run it showing

```
: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3006/primeng/primeng
<br> 
    Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3006/primeng/primeng
    Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3006/primeng/primeng
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as __zone_symbol___onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:3006/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1056:39)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3006/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:424:31)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3006/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:191:47)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3006/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:486:38)
    Error loading http://localhost:3006/primeng/primeng as "primeng/primeng" from http://localhost:3006/app/app.module.js
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as __zone_symbol___onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:3006/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1056:39)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3006/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:424:31)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3006/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:191:47)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3006/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:486:38)
    Error loading http://localhost:3006/primeng/primeng as "primeng/primeng" from http://localhost:3006/app/app.module.js
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your module too :

```
import {FileUploadModule} from 'primeng/primeng';

@Module({
    // ...
    imports: [FileUploadModule]
})
```

Comment: new error GET http://localhost:3006/primeng/components/fileupload/fileupload 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Could you upate your post instead of copy pasting the error in a comment ? It's really unreadable.

Comment: How to solve http://localhost:3006/primeng/primeng 404 (Not Found) issue ?

Comment: I don't know, you did something wrong, install it correctly (meaning that you have to follow the steps they tell you on their site). You provide no code, don't expect me to guess it for you.

Comment: Did you do as I said and installed it following their installation guide ? using `npm install`, adding the styles to the `angular-cli.json` file, etc. etc.